# Azure Data Factory Pipline Run FTP failure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that fails with the error:

```
Activity Copy_dbo_hosp_revenuek_lds_100_2016_demo failed: ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToReadFtpData,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to read data from ftp: The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.,Source=System,'
```

"... Not logged in..."? This is a little confusing because the FTP just worked when I was setting up the pipeline while following the steps in this article: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/cloud-data/using-copy-wizard-azure-data-factory/

I'm able to connect via command prompt and other FTP applications; why is Azure being difficult?  Did I miss a step?

Comment: Facing the same issue when trying to run the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable SSL in your FTP linked service? Does your FTP server support SSL?
If your ftp server doesn't support SSL, you can disable the SSL in FTP linked service. Check out the FTP properties here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp#linked-service-properties